# Modify and test an Android library from GitHub

Tags: java, android, github, android-library

I use for example library [Sweet Alert Dialog](https://github.com/pedant/sweet-alert-dialog). I want to modify this library by adding text size customization to `library/src/main/java/cn/pedant/SweetAlert/SweetAlertDialog.java`.

```
public SweetAlertDialog setTitleText (String text, int size) {
         mTitleText = text;
         int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, size, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
         if (mTitleTextView != null && mTitleText != null) {
             mTitleTextView.setText(mTitleText);
             mTitleTextView.setTextSize(height);
         }
         return this;
      }
```

Now I want to test this library and use it if it does what it should do. 
I need that one time explanation to get it. At the moment `GitHub` is a little bit confusing.

**UPDATE**

I have added this library via

```
dependencies {

    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'

}
```

Is there any way to just make your own compile path and test it? After branching the library or so?

Comment: You do need to change the compile path of the project. Just look at the sample folder's build.gradle for how that is done

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quickest way to obtain the library is to download it as ZIP file from GitHub.

Steps:

1. Navigate to https://github.com/pedant/sweet-alert-dialog in your browser.
2. Click on the <kbd>Clone or download</kbd> button (green).
3. Click on the <kbd>Download ZIP</kbd> button (blue).

See below:

[image]

To make changes to Sweet Alert Dialog, we will import it into Android Studio.

Steps:

1. Extract the contents of `sweet-alert-dialog-master.zip` file to disk e.g. `c:\sweet-alert-dialog-master`
2. Start Android Studio
3. From the Android Studio menu click File > New > Import Project
4. Select the `c:\sweet-alert-dialog-master` folder and click Ok.
5. Once the project is successfully imported, make necessary changes to the library.
6. Use the sample project to test your changes.

If the changes made to the Sweet Alert Dialog meet your requirements, we can proceed to use the Android archive (*.aar) file in our project.

Steps:

1. In Android Studio, open up an existing project that you want to use the Android archive file library.
2. Copy the `c:\sweet-alert-dialog-master\library\build\outputs\aarlibrary-release.aar` file in the `libs` directory (create it if needed) of your project.
3. Add the repositories section in the `app\build.gradle` file:

   ```
   repositories {
     flatDir {
       dirs 'libs'
     }
   }
   ```
4. Add the following line to the dependencies section:

   ```
   compile (name: 'library-release', ext:'aar')
   ```
5. Now the Sweet Alert Dialog contained in the Android archive file can be used in your app.

Comment: That part i do understand. But what to do next? I'll update the question

Comment: Sorry about that. Maybe it sounds silly but i havent done it before and all tutorials are confusing too.

Comment: I think import module is more correct than import project, but that depends on the end goal here. Modify the library in its own sample code, or use in separate project

Comment: The end goal is to hopefully use the library, provided the changes meet the acceptance criteria. So I thought it would be easier to make the changes and test in the sample project provided. If it meets the expectations we can then import the module.

Comment: Now it makes sense. As CliveSeebregts says open as new project make changes and test them. Then as cricket_007 says import as module and use as library. @CliveSeebregts could you update with how to add as module and use in project? This would be for everyone who wants same thing.

Comment: Sure, will do! Thanks for the help cricket_007 and Martynas

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use [JitPack](https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io).

It builds Git projects on demand and provides you with ready-to-use artifacts (jar, aar).

This way, you can fork the project, modify and test it. Then push it back to git and use that in your build script. Ideally, you would also create a pull request for your updates.

**Step 1.** Add the JitPack maven repository to the list of repositories:

```
url "https://jitpack.io"
```

**Step 2.** Add the dependency information:

- Group: com.github.Username
- Artifact: Repository Name
- Version: Release tag, commit hash or -SNAPSHOT

Gradle example:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.User:Repo:Version'
}
```

*Ensure you add the maven repo under `allprojects`, instead of `buildscript`.*